# Настройка CI Actions GitHub

Tags: java, spring, непрерывная-интеграция, github-actions

Есть приложение, которое использует имя и токен. Естественно в репозиторий я это не выложил. Создал отдельный файл env.properties (в .gitignore его прописал), который хранит их, а в application.properties уже так прописал.

```
spring.config.import=file:src/main/resources/env.properties
bot.username=${bot.hidden.username}
bot.token=${bot.hidden.token}
```

При пуше в удаленный репо у меня проходит проверка CI, но естественно она падает, т.к. не может достать имя и токен. Я создал имя и токен в разделе secrets на удаленном репозитории, но не могу понять как мне их подсунуть при проверке в файл

```
name: Java CI with Maven

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- name: Set up JDK 11
  uses: actions/setup-java@v3
  with:
    java-version: '11'
    distribution: 'temurin'
    cache: maven
- name: Build with Maven
  run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если верить [документации](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#accessing-your-secrets) по секретам, то вам нужно прокинуть их как переменные окружения в step, как-то так

```
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

spring понимает в переменные окружения, т.е. если у вас переменная называется `github.token`, то её можно задать как `GITHUB_TOKEN`

Comment: Попробовал по вашему совету, но все равно падает... Вижу что подгружается
env:
    JAVA_HOME: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/11.0.16-8/x64
    BOT_USERNAME: ***
    BOT_TOKEN: ***
Но дальше ошибка 
Config data resource 'file [src/main/resources/env.properties]' via location 'file:src/main/resources/env.properties' does not exist

Comment: @anton_63 получается надо убрать из конфига настройку `spring.config.import=file:src/main/resources/env.properties` и в общем случае запускать без неё, локально вы можете прокинуть эту настройку также через переменную окружения, например, тогда думаю всё взлетит

Comment: хмммм....печально конечно...получается других вариантов нету?

Comment: @anton_63 ну если в этом файле только Ваши секреты, то Вы можете  их задать так же через env переменные, тогда вообще не будет разницы между Вашим локальным окружением и окружением в github actions, иначе если прям хочется файл через настройки подключать, придётся как-то "приседать", не очень понятно зачем